# Naming not unique result error in python?

Tags: python, exception, naming-conventions

Maybe this is a little unconventional question but I'd like to hear an answer to it. Since english is not my native language I thought I'd ask for a second opinion.

I want to raise an Error in python and was wondering how to name it.

```
class AmbiguousResultError(Exception): pass
class NoResultFoundError(Exception): pass

def getUrlFor(mystring):
    list_of_urls = []
    # parse url object for all matching urls for the given string
    # and add them to list_of_urls
    if len(url) > 1:
        raise AmbiguousResultError("More then one url matches for {0}".format(mystring))
    elif not url:
        raise NoResultFoundError("There was no matching url for {0}".format(mystring))
    else:
        return list_of_urls[0]
```

The first `raise` is the one which I was wondering, how to name it such that it is precise. I thought of

1. `NoUniqueResultFoundError`
2. `AmbiguousResultError`
3. `UncertainResultError`

But they all don't satisfy me, and I don't know if I hit the nail with this nameing. It should be obvious to others, too. There has to be a specific expression for that. Which one is it. I thought of asking it on english.stackexchange.com, but I think a programmer has another sort of thinking then a philologist.

Comment: That `raise` syntax is deprecated; instantiate the exception.

Comment: `raise SomeException(arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: My question is: Does it even matter if you call it 'x' or 'y' if `More then one url matches for given string` explains the problem further? That's why raising an exception class is deprecated, as said above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer `AmbiguousStringError` to `AmbiguousResultError`.  After all, it's not the result that has multiple meanings, it's the string the user provided.

Or possibly `MultipleResultsFoundError`. I think your suggestion of `NoUniqueResultFoundError` is as good as anything though.  If you're as thorough and thoughtful with the rest of your code as you are with this, other developers won't have a problem debugging it.

Comment: I am trying. Thanks, for your suggestions! ;-)